# Go through list of dictionaries and select only rows where a key is present

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I search a list of dictionaries and only select rows where a certain key is present (regardless of value)? For example, in these three rows, I'd like to only keep those where `"userid"` is present (last two).

```
[{'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None},
 {'userid': '113503286', 'long': '-87.624387', 'tweetid': '595084326489956352', 'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'}, 
 {'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798', 'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179', 'lat': '41.878114'}]
```

I have tried the following code, but I get an error:

```
datum = [ row for row in data if row['tweet_time'] in row]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#102>", line 1, in <module>
datum = [ row for row in data if ['tweet_time'] in row]
```

Comment: Could you provide the *actual traceback* and a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code? At the moment, you've crashed them into each other and left little of any use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> [row for row in data if row['tweet_time'] in row]
> ```

Nope. But almost. Containment checking on a `dict` checks if the key exists.

```
[row for row in data if 'userid' in row]
```

Answer (score 3):

also lambda function works...

```
a = [{'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None}, {'userid': '113503286', 'long': '-87.624387', 'tweetid': '595084326489956352', 'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'}, {'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798', 'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179', 'lat': '41.878114'}]
b = filter(lambda x:"userid" in x, a)
print b
```

Answer (score 1):

And competing for first place in the category of "overly engineered solutions:" Adam Smith submits this piece entitled *Hey, let's use a database!*

```
# /models.py

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Numeric

Base = declarative_base()

class Tweet(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tweets"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    userid = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    tweetid = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    timestamp = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    long = Column(Numeric, nullable=False)
    lat = Column(Numeric, nullable=False)
```

```
# /main.py

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext import IntegrityError
from models import Tweet, Base

PATH_TO_DB = "tweet_info.db"

engine = create_engine(r"sqlite:///{}".format(PATH_TO_DB))
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()

d = [{'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None},
     {'userid': '113503286', 'long': '-87.624387',
      'tweetid': '595084326489956352',
      'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'},
     {'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798',
      'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179',
      'lat': '41.878114'}]

tweets = []
for tweetinfo in d:
    try:
        tweet = Tweet(**tweetinfo)
    except TypeError:
        continue
    else:
        tweets.append(tweet)

for tweet in tweets:
    session.add(tweet)
    try:
        session.commit()
    except IntegrityError:
        session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way, for how I understand your question:

```
dicts = [{'long': None, 'tweetid': None, 'timestamp': None, 'lat': None},
 {'userid': None, 'long': '-87.624387', 'tweetid': '595084326489956352', 'timestamp': '1430714134224', 'lat': '41.852653'}, 
 {'userid': '2421024865', 'long': '-87.629798', 'tweetid': '595084376632729600', 'timestamp': '1430714146179', 'lat': '41.878114'}]
print dicts

dicts = [d for d in dicts if "userid" in d and not d["userid"] == None]
print dicts
```

EDIT: Removed d.keys() thanks to a comment

Comment: You can remove "and not d["userid"] == None" if you don't care if it has the value None of course

Comment: you can actually remove everything from `.keys()` until the end bracket. `d.__iter__` is the list of keys, so calling `.keys()` only serves to build a list you never use.

Comment: And if you **do** want to excluse `d['userid'] == None`, you could do `[d for d in dicts if d.get('userid', None) is not None]`